# What happens when using IHTMLElement5/6 (for IE8/9) in IE6/7? Does it divert to IHTMLElement behaviour?

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, dom, attributes

Basically, IHTMLElement5 and IHTMLElement6 are all extended interfaces for the main IHTMLElement as per the versioning rules below:

```
IHTMLElement    IE4
IHTMLElement2   IE5
IHTMLElement3   IE5.5
IHTMLElement4   IE6
IHTMLElement5   IE8
IHTMLElement6   IE9
```

Of course, each new extended interface has the old members in it + its own new members, properties etc. However, some of the members (for instance, .getAttribute) are the same name but have been updated. So, my question is, if I use (say) IHTMLElement6 to declare my HTML Element and run the code on a client that only has IE6 installed, when will my object just fail and remain as Null/Nothing when I set it, or is mshtml.dll smart enough to realize whats going on and defaults to IHTMLElement4 (actually, IHTMLElement) behaviour?

Just to clarify the last statement in brackets, .getAttribute was added in IHTMLElement and updated in IHTMLElement5 and IHTMLElement6 - so, if someone has IE6 installed only, then I would expect the behaviour to default/revert back to IHTMLElement (not IHTMLElement4) - and if it does not do that, then I expect my code to crash. Basically, my question is, what will happen exactly?

Right now, because I am scared like crazy, I just declare everything as IHTMLElement, any ideas?

Thanks.

**Summary of Question (read if you find necessary, just a reclarification for those who need it):**
Basically, I want to be able to declare something as IHTMLElement6 so I can make use of the updated methods which have the same name between IHTMLElement and IHTMLElement6 (such as .getAttribute). This way, on IE9 users IHTMLElement6's version of .getAttribute will be taken advantage of, while at the same time IHTMLElement's version of .getAttribute will still work for (say) IE6 users without breaking my code - this is the point where my question comes in, when using a IHTMLElement6 object, even though it is an IE9 interface, will IHTMLElement's (IE4 interface) version of .getAttribute kick in/work or will I get a null reference exception or other runtime error? Thanks all.

The more responses, the better, even if it is your opinion and you don't know as a fact, I would like to encourage you to still comment while letting us know if you know this as a fact or if it is just opinion/guess etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that in older versions of IE that don't support `IHTMLElement6`, casting a DOM element to `IHTMLElement6` will fail with an `InvalidCastException`. You won't get a chance to call `IHTMLElement6.getAttribute()` because you won't be able to obtain a valid `IHTMLElement6` reference in the first place.

If this is correct, then what you're already doing (using `IHTMLElement`) seems like the correct course of action.

**UPDATE:** My suspicion was correct. I wrote a WinForms app that references the version of mshtml.dll that comes with IE9. On a system with IE9, the app successfully casts an `<img>` element to `IHTMLElement6`. But on a system with IE8, the same cast fails:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLImgClass' to interface type 'mshtml.IHTMLElement6'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{305106F8-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: thank you so much for your comments, I just wanted to ask how certain you are about this, and also would like to invite others to comment on what they know or even if it is only their guess, that is fine too. I was hoping this wasn't the case but if it is, I'm glad to know as I didn't know which way I should be doing things (ie: what was best programming practice re this issue). Once again, thank you for yout comments, upvoted, but will keep the question open to gather some more opinion from anyone willing to participate. Cheers mate.

Comment: Your awesome! Thanks for the test, that clarifies our question now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are supporting older browsers like IE6, then as per the specification .getAttribute will fail and will popup an error in the js on IE6. To avoid this from happening you'll have to handle in such a way that if the code fails then it should fail silently.

So wherever you have used .getAttribut, just put a if condition check whether this property exists, if doesn't exist the use the older property i.e .getAttributeNode else use .getAttribute

For e.g

```
if(obj.getAttribute){
   return obj.getAttribute;
}else{
   return obj.getAttributeNode;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i added a summary to my question for anyone that needs it, basically, my question is more so regarding if i can use the IHTMLElement6 interface/object and still have IE4's version of .getAttribute honoured for IE6 users, since .getAttribute was added in IE4 and updated in IE8 and IE9, does this make sense? Was hoping that I don't need to do version checks and declare IHTMLElement for IE6 & 7 users and then IHTMLElement5 for IE8 users and IHTMLElement6 for IE9 users, was just wanting to use IHTMLElement6 and have it work for all versions, right now im using IHTMLElement only to be safe.