# Coding a BHO targeting IE7

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++, com, bho

Context: after some code modifications, my BHO doesn't work anymore with IE7.

The problem: I use QueryInterface on an IHTMLElement for IHTMLElement5, and result is 0x80004002 (No such interface supported).

I remender that some time ago, the MSDN documentation on [Scripting Object Interfaces (MSHTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801967.aspx) would have indicated which version of IE supported each interface. This is no more the case. The IHTMLElement5 [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288596.aspx) says "Windows XP with SP2"... I think it's wrong, but anyway, now to my question:

**How to make my Visual Studio 2010 C++ build fail if I want to support IE7 and use IHTMLElement5?**

I searched the subject with google and SO, and found that there is a #define, _WIN32_IE that may be used to target a minimal specific IE version. My problem is that it doesn't change anything, all compile fine when I set the macro to _WIN32_IE_IE70

I searched the string '_WIN32_IE' in  (in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\mshtml.h) and found no match. Does it means that you can't make the build fail when setting the macro to _WIN32_IE_IE70 and using IHTMLElement5 in the code?

Answer (score 2):

[IHTMLElement5 isn't supported on IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619502/what-happens-when-using-ihtmlelement5-6-for-ie8-9-in-ie6-7-does-it-divert-to).  It's only supported on IE 8.  IE 8 is supported on XP, so the documentation is correct.

Unfortunately, _WIN32_IE isn't terribly useful any more; when Windows and IE were more closely bound, it was somewhat useful, but effectively anything > _WIN32_IE_60 is going to expose all the APIs that would be exposed.

Comment: The documentation is realy misleading when it just mentions OS version. I have a customer which (for whatever reasons) use IE7 on VISTA... Some time ago, the docs would have said "since IE8, blabla"